# How to retrive image from parse.com using php

Tags: php, image, parse-platform

I am trying to fetch the image which is already in parse database. In array I am getting the all the fetched data including the image URL but when I am trying to echo that particular URL it is echoing blank!! 
 Bellow is the code

```
     $object = new ParseQuery("billComputing");
     $getdata=$object->descending("updatedAt");
     $results = $object->find();
     $data=$results[0];  
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($results);
     echo "signature".$sign=$data->get('Signature["url"]');
```

In print_r() - I am getting this

```
[Signature] => Parse\ParseFile Object
                        (
                            [name:Parse\ParseFile:private] => tfss-8a4dbd13-7e16-4efc-abcf-08e901924f49-sign
                            [url:Parse\ParseFile:private] => http://files.parsetfss.com/864d47af-9eac-4b75-ae30-17b7352d16ca/tfss-8a4dbd13-7e16-4efc-abcf-08e901924f49-sign
                            [data:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                            [mimeType:Parse\ParseFile:private] => 
                        )
```

I am not able to display the URL. Appreciate help in advance.

Comment: `echo "signature".$sign=$data->get('Signature["url"]');`? You mean
`$sign=$data->get('Signature["url"]'); echo "signature".$sign;`?

Comment: Yes!!  $sign=$data->get('Signature["url"]');  echo "signature".$sign; This thing not showing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 $object = new ParseQuery("billComputing");
 $getdata=$object->descending("updatedAt");
 $results = $object->find();
 $data=$results[0];  
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($results);
 $file = $data->get('imageColumnName');
 $imageURL = $file->getURL();
 // you will get image url in $imageURL variable.
```

Comment: I'm not able to get the image from the URL. It comes back as Access denied. Any thoughts on a solution to this?